# what is the right way of resolving the Angularjs promises inside $q.all

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

I am facing problem with resolving the promises in using $q.all, can any one help me please?

When I have single promise, the following has worked fine:

```
 var dashlettePromise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);
    dashlettePromise.then(function(data) {
      var template = '<div class= "allChartsDiv">';

      for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < data.tabDetails.length; dashVar++) {
        var dashletteId = data.tabDetails[dashVar].dashletteId; // Added
         ....
      }
    }, function(error) {
      alert(error);
    }, function(progress) {
      // report progress
    });
```

But I need to make multiple ajax calls so I have used $q.all as shown below:

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray, function(dashboardslayout) {
  dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
  dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayout;
  var dashlettePromise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);
  promises.push(dashlettePromise);

});
```

Now I need to resolve all the promises in $q.all one by one exactly same as the one I have resolved for single promise as shown above. So I have used the code shown below but it is not working as expected. I am getting doubt on the logic I am using inside $q.all(promises) to resolve the promises. Is it right approach? or Can any one suggest the better approach to resolve the promises in $q.all?

```
$q.all(promises)
  .then(function(allData) {
    // all promises were resolved here                          
    angular.forEach(promises, function(eachPromise) {

      eachPromise.then(function(data) {

        for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < data.tabDetails.length; dashVar++) {
          var dashletteId = data.tabDetails[dashVar].dashletteId; // Added
          var axisType = data.tabDetails[dashVar].axisType;
            .....
        }

      }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
      })

    })

  });
```

Comment: Your first loop is useless : you shouldn't want to explicitly refer to `promises` inside the `then()` function, since you already have all the data in the `allData` array. Not sure if I'm clear enough.

Comment: What @Blackhole said, and also... do we really need to see all of the code you posted for you to ask about `$q.all`?

Comment: do you want me to do something like  angular.forEach(allData , function(data) {...}) inside then() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$q.all` does not return the promises themselves at a resolved state but rather returns their value directly. Thus although you'd like to get the promises inside the `$q.all` call you're getting the values. In order to circumvent this you access the promises in closure.

Try adjusting your code to deal with the values instead of the promises inside the `.all` call:

```
$q.all(promises)
  .then(function(allData) {
    // all promises were resolved here                          
    allData.forEach(function(data) {
    // no `then` needed here
        for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < data.tabDetails.length; dashVar++) {
          var dashletteId = data.tabDetails[dashVar].dashletteId; // Added
          var axisType = data.tabDetails[dashVar].axisType;
            .....
        }
    });
});
```

So in general your approach works (good job) - but can be better :)

Also note that progress events should probably be avoided and are not future proof.

Comment: I am accepting the answer but would like to echo to your comment, "So in general your approach works (good job) - but can be better ". What is the better option that you would suggest to me in this case?

Comment: One more question I have, is there any possibility to avoid the delays in collecting all the promises in queue and then resolving. The soon the promise is available I would like to resolve there itself. Relevant question can be found at stackoverflow.com/questions/27960174/how-to-minimize-the-delays-in-collecting-all-promises-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment44314227_27960174. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @mnkb the approach you had in the question (having then in the .all) works - but the approach not needing to demonstrated in the answer does not need that (thus it is better). I'll look at your other question.